# Ubunu Server not up to date Kernel

Tags: server, kernel, updates, vsftpd

I have two Ubuntu 14.04.05 Server. One is a ftp server(vsftpd, usermin, webmin) and the other one is a webserver(nginx).

The web server uses Kernel 4.4.0-36-generic, but
the fps server uses Kernel 3.13.0-95-generic.

```
webserver$ uname -a
Linux svr-web02 4.4.0-36-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 12 11:49:30 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ftpserver$ uname -a
Linux svr-ftp01 3.13.0-95-generic #142-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 12 17:00:09 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Both Server are regularly updated(once a month)

I am not sure why the ftp server doesn't get the new kernel(I used the same .iso ~2 Years ago)

Edit:
The ftp server has the package linux-generic installed the web server not.
When I try to install linux-generic on the web server, apt tells me that its going to install linux-image-3.13.0-98-generic.

Comment: Kernel 3.13 is the original one Trusty was released with. It is updated regularly, so there is no reason for it not to be uptodate. If you want to use the 4.4 kernel from Xenial - 16.04, install `linux-image-generic-lts-xenial` package.

Comment: ohh okay, but why does my web server has 4.4

Comment: Someone must have installed it at some point, and yes, linux-image-3.13.0-98-generic is the latest update to the 3.13 branch.

Comment: You're web server is running 14.04.1, but has the 4.4 kernel. This may have been an awkward attempt to deal with HWE upgrades that come with 14.04.2-5.  The ftp server may be on a different HWE and been upgraded in a more traditional method. 

You can check that with `lsb_release -a` to see the actual version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Also, if you are on 14.04.2-4 you should consider bringing it up to 14.04.5. 14.04.5 and 14.04.1 are the only ones with the full length LTS support.